# Java and Microsoft Access sql select command vs binary search

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I Am dealing with a database that contain 12 k records which method is faster to search for data using the select command or binary search ?

Comment: Where is the data?  In the database or in memory?  If the data is (already) in memory, then binary search will be faster.

Comment: data is in microsoft access file

Comment: How do you "binary search" a microsoft access file?  Is it possible?

Comment: select  column from database into a  vector and  Apply binary search on it

Comment: So ... you are searching in-memory after reading the database.  Well my comment above stands!

Comment: Yes i removed the binary search and worked with select   Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBMS are designed to process large amount of data. I think a select would be much faster than a binary search.